# django taggit get all users tags from foreignkey lookup

Tags: django-taggit

I have the following model

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    tags = TaggableManager()
```

I'm trying t get all the tags for a user and the following query isn't working as expected

```
tags = Tag.objects.filter(entry__user=u)
```

This is using django-taggit

https://github.com/alex/django-taggit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like

```
tags = Tag.objects.filter(entry__user=u)
```

worked.. I must have had some bad code somewhere.